# assume $f(4 x-3)+f(3-4 x)=4 x$ find the $f(x)$

Tags: functions

assume $f(4 x-3)+f(3-4 x)=4 x$. find the $f(x)$

I did this:

$\begin{aligned}
& t=4 x-3
\\&f(t)+f(-t)=t+3
\\&f(-t)+f(t)=-t+3
\\\Rightarrow &f(t)+f(-t)=3
\end{aligned}$

and stucked here.

Comment: And what if $f(-t)=-f(t)$ or $f(-t)=f(t)$?

Comment: and $f(-t)=-f(t)$ is impossible!

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner  do you mean the question itself could be wrong?

Comment: No, only $f(-t)=-f(t)$ is impossible.

Comment: $\sin(-t)=-\sin(t)$.

Answer (score 7):

There can be no such function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$. As you already derived,
$$
f(t)+f(-t)=t+3
$$
must hold for all $t \in \Bbb R$, and therefore (substitute  $t$ by $-t$) also
$$
f(-t)+f(t)=-t+3 \, .
$$
Subtracting the equations gives $2t = 0$, which obviously cannot hold for all $t \in \Bbb R$.

Or shorter:
$$
 \text{Set }x = 0 \implies f(-3) + f(3) = 0 \\
 \text{Set }x = \frac 32 \implies f(3) + f(-3) = 6
$$

Comment: Sorry, not the original poster, but why can't 2t=0 for all real numbers?

Comment: @WilsonGuo: $2t = 0 \iff t = 0$.